# ltxdockit and non-latin characters

Tags: luatex, fontspec, greek, cyrillic, ltxdockit

I know that `ltxdockit` is not really a properly supported package. Still, I would welcome if someone could help me. `ltxdockit` seems to have problems with non-latin alphabets. The following example in `LuaLaTeX` gives me a strange result:

```
\documentclass{ltxdockit}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\begin{document}
Аэлита
ΦΧδ
\begin{ltxexample}
{Test}
{Аэлита}
{ΦΧδ}
\end{ltxexample}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following output:
[image]

As you can see, the non-latin text is printed, but is not inside the curly quotes. Any ideas, what's going on here?

Comment: `ltxexample` is a `lstlisting` environment in disguise and the `listings` package is known not to work with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and extended character set.

Comment: So there is no way to deal with this?

Comment: Try with `minted`,

Comment: Is there any news here?